# How does one define an inner product on the space $V=\mathbb{Q}_p^n$?

Tags: number-theory, inner-products, p-adic-number-theory

In J H H Chalk's paper "Algebraic Lattices", he defines the notion of a lattice in ultrametric space as the following:

> Given a non-archimedean field $K$ with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ and completion $\tilde{K}$,
>
> 1. The integer lattice is defined $\Lambda_0 = \mathcal{O}_K^n \subset V= \tilde{K}^n$,
> 2. A lattice $\Lambda$ in $V$ is the image of $\Lambda_0$ under an invertible $\tilde{K}$-linear function $\lambda$ that sends $V$ to itself. The determinant $d(\lambda) = |\det{\lambda}|$,
> 3. $\|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}\|=\max_{1\leq i \leq n}|x_i - y_i|$ for all $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y} \in V$ with entries $x_i, y_i$.

Define $K = \mathcal{Q}_p$ so its ring of integers is the $p$-adic integers. How can we define an inner product on this space that satisfies the properties of an inner product, e.g. to find the dual of a lattice?

Comment: What exactly are "the properties of an inner product" here, given that the field $\Bbb{Q}_p$ cannot be ordered (i.e. there is no notion of "$\ge 0$" for elements in $\Bbb{Q}_p$)?

Comment: For the purposes of defining the dual lattice Isn't enough that the bilinear form is non-degenerate? What Torsten said is, of course, true, but do we really need ordering to get dual lattices? Won't 
$$\Lambda^*=\{x\in K^n\mid (x,y)\in\mathcal{O}_K\ \text{for all $y\in\Lambda$}\}$$ do nicely?

Answer (score 1):

On the complete metric space $\mathbb{Q}_p^n$ we introduce the inner product as usual:
$$
(x,y)=x_1y_1+\cdots +x_ny_n
$$
for $x=(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,\ldots ,y_n)$. This satisfies the inequality
$$
|(x,y)|_p\le |x|_p\cdot |y|_p.
$$

Edit: As $K=\mathbb{Q}_p$ is not ordered, the usual third axiom $(x,x)> 0$ for $x\neq 0$ is commonly replaced by the axiom $(x,x)\neq 0$ whenever $x\neq 0$.

Comment: thank you! for clarification, how is the positive definiteness of this inner product proven?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the last comment. $\mathbb{Q}_p$ cannot be ordered, so a property like "$(x,x) \ge 0$" does not even make sense here. (Also, e.g. there is $x_1 \in \Bbb{Q}_2$  with $x_1^2 = -7$; so for the vector $x = (x_1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) \in \Bbb{Q}_2^8$, we have $(x,x) = 0$). Maybe there is a different defintion of "positive definite" here that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Yes, you are right, but for the non-archimedian case an "inner" product is defined accordingly, e.g., see [here](http://pucuch.mat.uc.cl/docume/100304120442.pdf), page $23$.

Comment: OK, but except for very small dimension $n$, that product will not even satisfy $(x,x) \neq 0$, see above example. Actually, it is a classical result (due to Witt?) that every quadratic form in $n \ge 5$ variables over a $p$-adic field is isotropic. However, of course your form is non-degenerate, and I think that should actually be good enough as per Jyrki's comment.

Comment: For $n=2$ if $p \equiv 1\bmod 4$ then $( (1,i), (1,i)) = 0$ and for $n \ge 3$ there is always a non-zero solution to $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=0$. In $\Bbb{Q}_3^2$, we have $(x,x) = 0 \implies x=0$ and the bilinear form is invariant under $O_2(\Bbb{Q}_3)$.